# How to replace the {} inside the string with dictionaries

Tags: python

```
 num= {1:'a',2: 'z'}

 a='{} is {}'.format(num[1],num[2])
 num[1] = "hello"
```

May I know why the variable 'a' is still same with the old one, although I have replaced it with other words by using slicing num[1]?

```
print(a)
 >>>
 a is z


num
>>>
{1: 'hello', 2: 'z'}
```

Comment: Because `a` was created with the previous values in `num`. `num[1]` is instantaneous, it's not a reference to what the `1`th value in `num` might change to at any given time, and strings are immutable anyway.

Comment: `num[1] = "hello"` must be before formatting the string

Comment: Because you never changed the variable `a` after you first defined it, why did you *expect it to change*? `a` has no inherent connection to `num`

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because you defined a before changing your dictionary, ordering of your code in python is important.

```
 num= {1:'a',2: 'z'}

 a='{} is {}'.format(num[1],num[2])
 num[1] = "hello"

print(a)
```

a is z

vs

```
num= {1:'a',2: 'z'}
num[1] = "hello"

a='{} is {}'.format(num[1],num[2])

print(a)
```

hello is z

Answer (score 0):

The assignment to variable `a` produces a static string based on the values of `num[1]` and `num[2]` at that point in the execution sequence.  Updating the dictionary afterward does not regenerate the value of `a`.

If you want `a` to change with the content of the dictionary, you need to make it an executable function or lambda so that it is re-evaluated each time you use it:

```
num= {1:'a',2: 'z'}

def a(): return '{} is {}'.format(num[1],num[2])

print(a()) # a is z

num[1] = "hello"

print(a()) # hello is z
```